# What is this "operator" block of code in c++ class

Tags: c++, bitset

I'm using someone's class for bitmaps, which are ways of storing chess positions in 64-bit bitsets. I was wondering what the part with `auto() operator` does. Is "auto" used because it returns one bit, which is why a return-type isn't specified for the function? I get that it checks that x and y are in the bounds of the chess board, and asserts an error if they aren't. I also understand that it returns a bit that corresponds to the x,y value pair for the bitset. I also don't get why the function is defined like it is, with an extra pair of parentheses. Any help is appreciated!

```
class BitBoard {
    private:
        std::bitset<64> board;
    public:
        auto operator()(int x, int y) {
            assert(0<=x && x<=7);
            assert(0<=y && y<=7);
            return board[8*y+x];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It's commonly called a *function call operator*. It allows an instance of the class, ex: `BitBoard bb;` , to be used like: `bb(1,2);` . See the section "Function call operator" in this encompassing question and answer: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1322972)

Comment: I can't believe there's no dupe for questions about what `operator()` means...

Comment: @einpoklum: There's the very general one Whoz linked, but `operator()` deserves additional detail about its use as a workaround for `operator[]` not accepting multiple arguments.

Comment: It’s not an extra set of parentheses. They’re part of the name of the operator, just like the `+` in `operator+`. The name of this operator is `operator()`, which is a function call operator. Yes, it’s confusing. <g>

Comment: `operator`-*something* in this context means you are overloading the *something* operator in your C++ class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "extra" pair of parentheses are because you're defining `operator()`, which lets instances of your class behave like functions. So if you had a:

```
BitBoard board;
```

you could get the value for `x=3`, `y=5` by doing:

```
board(3, 5)
```

instead of having a method you call on the board explicitly, like `board.get_bit_at(3, 5)`.

The use of `auto` just means it deduces the return type from `std::bitset<64>`'s `operator[]`; since the method isn't `const` qualified, this means it's just deducing the `std::bitset::reference` type that `std::bitset`'s `operator[]` uses to allow mutations via stuff like `mybitset[5] = true;`, even though you can't give "true" references to single bits. If reimplemented a second time as a `const`-qualified `operator()`, e.g.:

```
    auto operator()(int x, int y) const {
        assert(0<=x && x<=7);
        assert(0<=y && y<=7);
        return board[8*y+x];
    }
```

you could use `auto` again for consistency, though it doesn't save any complexity (the return type would be `bool` in that case, matching `std::bitset`'s `const`-qualified `operator[]`, no harder to type than `auto`).

The choice to use `operator()` is an old hack for multidimensional data structures to work around `operator[]` only accepting one argument; rather than defining `operator[]` to return a proxy type (which itself implements another `operator[]` to enable access to the second dimension), you define `operator()` to take an arbitrary number of arguments and efficiently perform the complete lookup with no proxies required.

Comment: Are you sure about "for `const BitBoard` objects the return type would be `bool`" ?   Having a deduced return type doesn't automatically make variations for different `this`-qualification, I believe this function just can't be used on a `const BitBoard` at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, I'm not sure. As written, I believe you're correct that it's only valid on non-`const BitBoard`, but if you defined both the `const` and non-`const` versions of `operator()` you could use `auto` on both definition, and one would be seamlessly a `std::bitset::reference`, while the other would be `bool`, without needing to get into the nitty-gritty. I'll clarify.

Comment: The qualification "if you defined both the `const` and non-`const` versions of `operator()`" I agree with

Comment: @BenVoigt: I just confirmed, and yes, a `const BitBoard` doesn't work as written, as suspected (though it works fine as soon as you define `auto operator()(int x, int y) const { return board[8*y+x]; }`). The updated answer should be fully correct now.

Answer (score 1):

`operator()` is the name of the function, which is then followed by another pair of parentheses listing the arguments. It is the function-call operator and overloading it allows you to make objects that act like functions/function pointers.  In this case, it allows:

```
BitBoard thing;
thing(i, j); // looks like a function!
```

In this particular case, it's being used for indexing (like `a[i]`) but the subscript operator `operator[]` doesn't allow multiple indexes and the function-call operator does.  So it was pretty common to see this for multi-dimensional arrays.

However, the new "preferred" style for multiple indexes in C++ is to pass a list to the subscript operator:

```
BitBoard thing;
std::cout << thing[{i, j}];
```

This would be accomplished by `operator[](std::array<int, 2> xy)`.

But the author of this class has chosen the old way, that looks like a function call.

Overloaded `operator()` is *also* what makes lambda expressions tick inside.